# how to replace \n to <br > in telegram instant view

Tags: xpath, telegram

I am trying to setup a Telegram Instant View for a website.

i have a text with a lot of break-lines `\n`  and no `<br>` so 
i need a solution to replace every `\n` to `<br>`

Answer (score 2):

Try [@replace](https://instantview.telegram.org/docs#replace) function:

```
@replace("\\n", "<br>"): $body//p
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way (in the Instant View DSL) to replace a part of a [text node](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Text-Nodes) with an HTML tag (i.e. [element node](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#element-nodes)). Any HTML you insert as text will be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember, if you debug `$paragraph/text()`, there will be a lot of text nodes, that are separated with `\n` in the original markup:

```
[0]: first line
[1]: second line
```

So, the only thing you need to do is just `@after(<br>): $paragraph/text()`.

---

It's better not to make a big long paragraph with `<br>` inside — split text on small `<p>`aragraphs.